# pygame joystick axis and buttons keep returning 0 in ubuntu linux in virtualbox

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame, virtualbox

Setup: Windows 10 host with Ubuntu 20.04 guest inside VirtualBox

I have recently switched virtual machines and am confused on why my joystick code wont work anymore.

I have this code that runs perfectly inside windows 10, and Ubuntu 20.04 guest inside VMware. However in VirtualBox it just prints 0's for all the axis's and buttons. I don't think any information is getting passed into the virtual machine other than the joystick memory location. After I turn on the usb from the VirtualBox devices tab, in my /dev the joystick is under "hidraw1" is that normal?

The code runs with no errors but it is just printing 0's. I have the VirtualBox extension pack and have a working webcam so I think the VM can access the usb's. I am just confused as to why no data is being passed. Any ideas?

Here is the code for reference,

```
import pygame
import math as m

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 90, 90
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

pygame.joystick.init()
joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
print(joysticks)
speed = 0
FPS = 60
con = 3
button_X = 0
button_A = 1
button_B = 2
print("init")
def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    speed = 0
    speed_time = 0.03
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        x_pos = pygame.joystick.Joystick(con).get_axis(0)
        y_pos = pygame.joystick.Joystick(con).get_axis(1)
        B_A = pygame.joystick.Joystick(con).get_button(button_A)
        B_B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(con).get_button(button_B)
        B_X = pygame.joystick.Joystick(con).get_button(button_X)

        #Set speed control
        if B_A:
            speed = speed + speed_time
            if speed > 1:
                speed = 1.0
        elif B_B:
            speed = speed - speed_time
            if speed < -1:
                speed = -1.0
        else:
            if speed > 0:
                speed = speed - speed_time
                if speed < 0:
                    speed = 0
            elif speed < 0:
                speed = speed + speed_time
                if speed > 0:
                    speed = 0
        #Filter signal
        if B_X:
            speed = 0
        if x_pos < 0.2 and x_pos > -0.2:
            x_pos = 0.0
        if x_pos > 0.75:
            x_pos = 1
        if x_pos < -0.75:
            x_pos = -1
        if y_pos < 0.2 and y_pos > -0.2:
            y_pos = 0.0
        if y_pos > 0.75:
            y_pos = 1
        if y_pos < -0.75:
            y_pos = -1
        x_float = "{:.2f}".format(x_pos)
        y_float = "{:.2f}".format(y_pos)
        speed_value = "{:.2f}".format(speed)
        angle = m.atan2(y_pos,x_pos)
        deg = angle * -180/m.pi
        pos = [x_float, y_float]
        deg = "{:.2f}".format(deg)
        print("Angle = ", deg, " Pos = ", pos, " Speed = ", speed_value)
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example Output:

```
pygame 2.0.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.10)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[<Joystick object at 0x7ff4dd1893c0>, <Joystick object at 
0x7ff4dd163ba0>, <Joystick object at 0x7ff4dd24d3f0>, <Joystick object 
at 0x7ff4dd24d030>]
init
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
Angle =  -0.00  Pos =  ['0.00', '0.00']  Speed =  0.00
...
```

Returns all 0, despite moving the sticks around.

Comment: This problem is related to your system, but not to your code. All of this code and data is nice, but it doesn't help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. Glad its not the code. Just trying to figure out right now if its windows or virtualbox that blocking the data. Or is it possible that its reading the wrong memory location?